# Loop to Find Dependencies

Tags: vba, excel

I have data on a sheet named 'Dependencies' like you see in the image below.  The actual data is slightly different, but this example will illustrate the point.

[image]

```
Here is the data:
    Category Name   Dependencies
    Beverages   SoftDrinks
    Beverages   Coffees
    Beverages   Teas
    Beverages   Beers
    Beverages   Andales
    Condiments  Sweetandsavorysauces
    Condiments  Relishes
    Condiments  Spreads
    Condiments  Andseasonings
```

I have another sheet classically named 'Sheet1'.  It looks like this.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I am trying to figure out how to create a Macro to produce a final result like this.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

So, basically, I need to check the value in Cell B2 in Sheet 1, find all matches in ColumnA of the Dependencies sheet, and concatenate all values in the adjacent cells, in ColumnB.  The results have to be concatenated together, with line-breaks between each value.  Also, I need to have the ID in Sheet1 appended into the final result.

I tried a few things like Vlookups, and Index/Match, but couldn’t get anything working.  I’m sure it’s possible with VBA.  I just don’t know exactly how to do it.  I’m still testing some ideas.  I’ll post back with any updates that I have.  If someone can figure this out before I do, please share your answer.

Thanks to all!

I’m back in my office now and testing this on my actual data set.  **There is a slight flaw in the logic so the row number is off.**  I need to do some kind of lookup between Dependence and TaskTitle, and take the number of the TaskTitle.  Look at the image below.

[image]

So, this: 3. Complete Fair Lending Attestation SHOULD be this: 1. Complete Fair Lending Attestation.  Also, this 4. Update Fair Lending Tollgate Information SHOULD be this: 3. Update Fair Lending Tollgate Information.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Will the macro plot the whole output (Category ID and Category Name) or just plot the dependencies?

Comment: Just the Dependencies in ColC.  Right now I have some data in Sheet1 in ColA and ColB.  I need to get ColC filled in, following the rules I outlined above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the name of your sheets in the code are "Sheet1" and "Dependencies", and the data start in Column 1 in each sheet (Row 3 in sheeet1 and row 2 in Dependences) the next code should produce the output you want

```
Sub solve()
   Dim i As Long, j As Long
   Dim searchVal As String, ID As String, findVal As String, dependence As String, resultVal As String

   i = 3
   'The first While will loop all values present in colum 2 of Sheet1'
   Do While (Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "")
      searchVal = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value 'The value you need match in Dependences'
      resultVal = "" 'the value you need to calculate'
      j = 2 'also need to reset the index of second loop'
      ID = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value 'The id present in column 1'

      'The second While loops the Dependences Sheet'
      Debug.Print "FirstLoop: " & searchVal
      Do While (Sheets("Dependencies").Cells(j, 1).Value <> "")
         findVal = Dependences.Cells(j, 1).Value
         dependence = Dependences.Cells(j, 2).Value

         Debug.Print "key: " & findVal & ", dependence: " & dependence
         If (searchVal = findVal) Then 'if you find a coincidence, you will modify the result string'
            resultVal = resultVal & ID & ". " & dependence & Chr(10)
         End If

         j = j + 1
      Loop

      'finally, we writhe the result string in olumn 3'
      Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = resultVal
      i = i + 1
   Loop

End Sub
```

if you have any question, let me know. Hope this help you

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks so much!!  I just made a tiny tweak...
Do While (Sheets("Dependencies").Cells(j, 1).Value <> "")
I think that Sheet1 was literally doing the operations on the first Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Let me know if you have questions.

```
'Place Macro on Dependency Sheet
Public Sub genMain()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dbArray As Variant
    Set ws = Worksheets(Me.Name)

    'gets list on Dependencies stores to Array
    dbArray = ws.Range("A2:B2", ws.Range("A2:B2").End(xlDown))
    Set ws = Nothing

    'plots to sheet1
    Set ws = Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)
    With ws
        Dim TotalRows As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim LastCol As Long
        ws.Select
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
        .Range("A2").Resize(LastRow - 1, LastCol).Select
        TotalRows = Selection.Rows.Count + 1
        Dim temp As String

        For Row = 2 To TotalRows Step 1
            temp = ""
            For col = 1 To LastCol Step 1
                If .Cells(1, col).Value Like "*Dependency*" Then 'scans all columns
                    For i = 1 To UBound(dbArray) 'searches the dbArray
                        If dbArray(i, 1) = .Cells(Row, col - 1).Value Then 'matches current Category Name with the dbArray current selection
                            If temp = "" Then
                                temp = dbArray(i, 2) ' if cell is empty
                            Else
                                temp = temp & vbCrLf & dbArray(i, 2) 'enter new line and enter dependency
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            Next col
            .Cells(Row, col - 1).Value = temp
        Next Row
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That didn't do what I want, Hexxed.  But, the script posted by Fernando CT worked perfect, so I'm all set now.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Fernando CT, I just found a flaw in the logic.  Please see my OP.  I modified it to describe the issue I just encountered.

Comment: I figured it out.  All set now.  Thanks a lot Fernando CT!!